# My .htaccess RewriteRule stopped working after upgrading to Apache/2.4.28 (cPanel)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My RewriteRule stopped working when I moved my website to a new hosting company with the latest cPanel.

I'm not sure if cPanel's new security is blocking this redirect or it is not compatible with the new Apache/2.4.

My old RewriteRule which is not working:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(resources)/(.*)/$ resources/index.php?u=$2 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Basically, I want to 301 redirect links:
http://example.com/resources/index.php?name=ic

to:
http://example.com/resources/ic/

Regular Expression and RewriteRule is so code based and complicated, I cannot figure it out.

I really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "is blocking"? Why do you think so? What does your error log file say?

Comment: No errors because it works opposites. Instead of redirecting From: http://example.com/resources/index.php?name=ic To: http://example.com/resources/ic/, it redirects From: http://example.com/resources/ic/ To: http://example.com/resources/index.php?name=ic

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to make any sense of your comment...

Comment: You write "no errors"... I do not care of is happening on your old system. Question is if you receive some errors from the rewriting engine on the new system. Just _claiming_ that is not the case is one thing, but somehow I have the impression you did not even check the error log file on the new system...

Comment: [Tue Oct 24 13:15:56.973618 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30365] AH00163: Apache/2.4.28 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2k mod_bwlimited/1.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 24 13:15:56.973630 2017] [core:notice] [pid 30365] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd'
[Tue Oct 24 14:15:52.416219 2017] [core:crit] [pid 28321] (13)Permission denied: [client 115.231.218.76:3207] AH00529: /home/bison/public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/bison/public_html/' is executable

Comment: Thank you for writing, as you notice in my above error log, there is no error regarding my access. Let's assume that I do not even have the above 301 redirect RewriteRule code. If you were to write a 301 redirect RewriteRule, to redirect FROM: example.com/resources/index.php?name=ic To: example.com/resources/ic To: example.com/resources/ic/  How would you write the rewrite rule?

Comment: Ok, so the issue is a file system permission issue: the http server fails to read the dynamic configuration file. In general you should _always_ prefer to place such rule in the real server configuration files instead of these dynamic configuration files (".htaccess").

Comment: About your rewriting rule: looks more or less fine to me. What is the specific question you have? Any specific issues with it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I never had any issues with including .htaccess file inside public_html folder. In fact, I believe this is a common practice in most CMS applications. Why is it an issue now to include .htaccess inside public_html folder? I ended up signing up with another VPS Cloud ISP and they provided me with the same version of WHM/cPanel as the previous ISP, and I have no problem with my .htaccess and RewriteRule now, so I'm still not sure what the problem is with the old ISP setup, but I know now that it is more likely an issue with the previous ISP configuration of the server.

Comment: The error message you receive is clear: the process tries to include the dynamic configuration file but fails due to a permission issue. Most likely this simply means that the system account the http server process is executed under has no read access to the file you created yourself. Typically that is a question of you using a different user account for an upload and should change your accounts umask setting. A first step would be to find out the permission set of that configuration file and what user and group account it is owned by. This may very well differ between service providers, sure.

Comment: In general the usage of such dynamic configuration file is only supported as a last option. Those files are notoriously error prone, really hard to debug and they really slow down the http server, often for nothing. In 99% of all cases it is better to not use them but place rewriting rules inside the http servers host configuration section.